# Time and Price estimate for the Ride Request Button of UBER don't appear

Tags: uber-api

I followed the sample on how a Ride Request Button of Uber will for Android apps. All is okay until I want to display the time estimate and price for my desired destination.

Here is my code:

```
//setting the uber config
private void setupUberConfig() {
    uberSessionConfig = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(getString(R.string.uber_client_id))
            .setServerToken(getString(R.string.uber_server_token))
            .setClientSecret(getString(R.string.uber_client_secret))
            .setRedirectUri("http://www.upnixt.com")
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.REQUEST))
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
            .build();
    UberSdk.initialize(uberSessionConfig);
}


new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return currentPlace.getUberXProductId(mContext, MainActivity.getCurrentLocationForOthers().getLatitude(), MainActivity.getCurrentLocationForOthers().getLongitude(),
                    getString(R.string.uber_server_token));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String productId) {
            super.onPostExecute(productId);
            callUber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RideParameters rideParams;
            if (productId != null) {
                 rideParams = new RideParameters.Builder()
                        .setProductId(productId)
                        .setPickupLocation(MainActivity.getCurrentLocationForOthers().getLatitude(), MainActivity.getCurrentLocationForOthers().getLongitude(), "", "")
                        .setDropoffLocation(currentPlace.getLat(), currentPlace.getLng(), currentPlace.getName(), currentPlace.getAddress())
                        .build();
            } else {
                rideParams = new RideParameters.Builder()
                        .setPickupLocation(MainActivity.getCurrentLocationForOthers().getLatitude(), MainActivity.getCurrentLocationForOthers().getLongitude(), "", "")
                        .setDropoffLocation(currentPlace.getLat(), currentPlace.getLng(), currentPlace.getName(), currentPlace.getAddress())
                        .build();
            }

            callUber.setRideParameters(rideParams);
            ServerTokenSession session = new ServerTokenSession(uberSessionConfig);
            callUber.setSession(session);
            callUber.setCallback(new RideRequestButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onRideInformationLoaded() {
                    Log.d("SELLE", "Info Loaded");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ApiError apiError) {
                    Log.d("SELLE", apiError.getClientErrors().get(0).getTitle());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.d("SELLE", "Info Loaded");
                }
            });
            callUber.loadRideInformation();

        }
    }.execute();
```

I get the product id from v1/products API of Uber.
Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, use the lat + long and v1/products endpoint to get the relevant product_id. What error are you running into?

Comment: @DustinWhittle I already added lat and long to the v1/products api and got the relevant product_id for UberX type of trip. then included this to the ride param for the button. Actually there's no error but the button does not display the time and price estimate when I call this method loadRideInformation(). BTW, I'm located in the Philippines might have issue on this